# Learning xml for android development

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

Is it recommended to learn xml to create user interfaces for android apps?
It's pretty easy to do in the layout editor of android studio, but I feel like it would be better to learn to write the layout code myself so I'm not dependent on the editor.

Comment: Yes, it is pretty straightforward tough, you should never use the layout editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is recommended to learn the xml.

You won't be able to use the visual editor for every layout you use. When you are using the visual editor it may use hardcoded values and add some unwanted attributes, giving the users an bad UI depending on their devices.

Currently, the only layout that using the visual editor might be a good idea is the [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html). But even for it, you might need to fix some generated xml code.

Comment: Didn't know that, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's ALWAYS important to learn the basics of any "coding or language" instead of just playing around with the IDE, this should help you in the future for looking for errors or any changes. In case of XML it will help you to use it in other programming languages too.

Comment: That's true, thank you!